can't start react-native Cannot use import statement outside a module: react-native/index.js: import ActionSheetIOS from './Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/A
I suddenly couldn't run my app anymore, I don't even remember what I did to get to this point. I've reinstalled my node_modules multiple times, updated my node version, but nothing works.
% sudo npx react-native start --reset-cache
error Cannot use import statement outside a module.
/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/react-native/index.js:14
import ActionSheetIOS from './Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/ActionSheetIOS';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1281:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at get AsyncStorage [as AsyncStorage] (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/asyncstorage-down/default-opts.js:3:12)
    at new AsyncStorageCore (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/asyncstorage-down/asyncstorage-core.js:11:33)
    at new Storage (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/asyncstorage-down/asyncstorage.js:9:17)

Searching up this problem, some recommended adding "type":"module" to my package.json. But doing that caused this:
error Failed to load configuration of your project.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/react-native.config.js from /Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js not supported.
react-native.config.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead either rename react-native.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at module.exports (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js:28:9)
    at loadJs (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js:9:18)
    at Explorer.loadFileContent (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/createExplorer.js:230:12)
    at Explorer.createCosmiconfigResultSync (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/createExplorer.js:263:31)
    at Explorer.loadSearchPlaceSync (/Users/tarioyou/Safeplate/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/createExplorer.js:158:17)

babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      [
        'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
        {
          useTransformReactJSXExperimental: true,
        },
      ],
      'module:@react-native/babel-preset',
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module:react-native-dotenv',
        {
          moduleName: '@env',
          path: '.env',
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};

metro.config.js:
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const {assetExts, sourceExts} = defaultConfig.resolver;

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    extraNodeModules: {
      fs: require('react-native-level-fs'),
      path: require('path'),
      crypto: require('react-native-crypto'),
      http: require('@tradle/react-native-http'),
      https: require('https-browserify'),
      os: require('react-native-os'),
    },
  },
});

